# urls.py icon doesn't have an image of python on it in PyCharm

Tags: python, django, url, pycharm

I'm working on Django project in PyCharm enviroment. I have a strange problem: In all of my Django apps urls.py files do not have an emblem of python on their icons. And, I do not have an IDLE support for the code. If the name of the file is changed, then the file becomes common python script.
I cannot understand why this is happening?

**EDITED:**

Tried to define a variable inside of the file, and import it into another script. Got the next error:
*ImportError: cannot import name 'appUrlName' from partially initialized module 'tables.urls' (most likely due to a circular import)*

And i have that problem in EVERY django project. Even in new ones.
I guess, maybe this is not a problem, but a feature of django.

Illustration:

[image: urls.py without python emblem]

Comment: Perhaps the filename has a space at the end, or some other character that we can't see?

Comment: @JohnGordon No, I can't find any. Tried to rename and to create new project.

Comment: do you have a specific config in Setting | Editor | File Types ?

Comment: @EricMartin is probably correct, `urls.py` seems to have the "text" file type.

Comment: imo, you misclicked  and add a rule on urls.py. i ll post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably misclick and add urls.py in a file name patterns for text file.

Go to Settings/ Editor / File type
Then Text
and delete this pattern

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also right click the file -> File Type Override -> Python

It worked for me since my file wasn't in the settings' patterns.